# Архитектура построения сложной системы фильтрации сущностей в web-приложении

Tags: java, sql, фильтр, данные

Есть веб-приложение на java, у которого основная сущность - возьмём для примера -книга, содержит около 30 полей. Одна из функций приложения - проходиться по таблице с книгами, и отдавать те, что подходят под запрошенные критерии.
Критерии приходят с фронта в виде запроса с десятком параметров. В зависимости от значения параметров, принимаются решения и составляется SQL запрос.

Сейчас фильтрация производится с помощью большой лапши из `if-else` и `switch`, которой приложение со временем обрастало. И, тут, возникла возможность систему фильтрации переписать. Поэтому встал вопрос, а какие удачные архитектурные решения для этого существуют? Чтобы система получилась максимально гибкой и расширяемой в будущем. Буду благодарен за статьи, книги или же просто личный опыт в проектировании сложных систем фильтрации данных.

Comment: Если вам нужно что то кардинальное, то я бы глядел на системы, специально разработанные под поиск, типа elastic. Если вы просто отрефакторить свою функцию для построения SQL хотите, то приведите её и опишите, чем она вам не нравится и что вы бы погли с ней сделать.

Comment: для проектирования таких систем рекомендуется использовать паттерн под названием "Цепочка обязанностей". Суть в том, что каждое условие для фильтрации - это отдельный класс-фильтр, принимающий в аргументы метода запрос, анализирующий его и знающий, исходя из параметров, находящихся в запросе, отрабатывать ему или нет. Запрос передается по цепочке из таких фильтров. Вторым параметром вы можете, например, передавать результат работы фильтра, который будет модернизироваться каждым из классов-фильтров, и возвращаться методом, как результат выполнения.

Comment: Все такие классы - фильтры имеют единственный метод и имплементируют один интерфейс. Таким образом на выходе вы получаете цепь классов-фильтров, передающих друг-другу запрос и возвращающих результат, модернизированный всеми по очереди. Можете скрестить его с декоратором и инжектить в переменную типа интерфейса , находящуюся в конструкторе, бин по имени, если одной цепочки мало (недостаточная гибкостть). Читается легко, расширяется легко, пишется тоже не сложно.

Answer (score 1):

***Внимание!**  Данный способ не рекомендуется для серьёзных систем.
У него часто случаются проблемы с производительностью, так как это
издевательство над планировщиком.*

Вообще, вам надо использовать инструменты для создания динамического
*SQL*, которые есть в ваших библиотеках.  Но если вам нужен ручной
*SQL* с небольшим количеством `if`, и вам наплевать на
производительность и красоту запроса, можете использовать древний шаблон
`IS NULL OR`:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM books
 WHERE ($book_id_eq   IS NULL OR book_id   =  $book_id_eq)
   AND ($author_id_eq IS NULL OR author_id =  $author_id_eq)
   AND ($shop_id_eq   IS NULL OR shop_id   =  $shop_id_eq)
   AND ($rating_ge    IS NULL OR rating    >= $rating_ge)
   AND ($rating_le    IS NULL OR rating    <= $rating_le)
/* Ad nauseam.  */
;
```

Когда параметры нулевые, условие «пропускается», а когда ненулевые,
«активируется».  В вашей ситуации это будет как раз ваш «десяток
параметров».