# MySQL. Параметр null == любое значение

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Дана таблица

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `p1` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `p2` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `p3` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `p4` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `p5` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `p1`, `p2`,`p3`,`p4`,`p5`) VALUES
  ('1', '2', '3', '5', '1', '9'),
  ('2', '1', '2', '9', '6', '4'),
  ('3', '3', '3', '2','1', '9'),
  ('4', '2', '6', '1', '7', '8'),
  ('5', '3', '3', '1', '2', '7'),
  ('6', '3', '2', '1', '8', '3'),
  ('7', '1', '4', '2', '3', '2'),
  ('8', '5', '9', '7', '4', '1');
```

Нужно написать запрос, в который вместо %p1..%p5 можно подставить значения параметров или null. Если параметр null, то у возвращенных записей этот параметр **может быть любым**.

-- SELECT * FROM docs WHERE p1=%p1 and p2=%p2 and p3=%p3 and p4=%p4 and p5=%p5

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Архитектура построения сложной системы фильтрации сущностей в web-приложении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1043929/%d0%90%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-web-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Что значит? Если параметр null, то у возвращенных записей этот параметр может быть любым.? Любое rnd значения генерировать и туда вставить?

Comment: Имеется ввиду эквивалент is not null

Answer (score 1):

То, что предлагает Ainar-G в [другом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1043929/%d0%90%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-web-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8) будет работать:

```
SELECT * 
FROM docs 
WHERE (%p1 IS NULL OR p1=%p1) 
AND   (%p2 IS NULL OR p2=%p3) 
...
AND   (%p5 IS NULL OR p5=%p5)
```

Но лучше 5 IF в приложении чтобы создать запрос с доступными параметрами, чем такое решение. Поработайте еще раз над дизайном.